# AWS SAM - Template does not have any APIs connected to Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

So I'm trying to convert an existing spring boot application to an AWS lambda and using SAM.

I'm trying to use aws-sam-cli to try my lambda locally, however with my SAM setup I am getting: `Template does not have any APIs connected to Lambda functions`

When I do: `sam local start-api`

My `template.yml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: foo
Resources:
  MailFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: bar.LambdaHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: target/foo-bar-1.0.jar
      Timeout: 300
      MemorySize: 1024
      Events:
        Timer:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: rate(1 day)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? It looks correct as far as I can tell from https://blog.couchbase.com/aws-serverless-lambda-scheduled-events-tweets-couchbase/ + https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You didn't add any API Gateway event to your function. And `start-api` spawn a local API Gateway.

You need to add at least one `Api` event to your `Events` section.

```
Events:
  [...]
  Api:
    Type: Api
    Properties:
      Path: /myresource
      Method: get
```

If you just have a `Schedule` event, try to use `generate-event` to create such an event.

`sam local generate-event schedule ...`

and invoke function e.g. `sam local invoke function-name -e event_file.json` ([see](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/test-sam-cli.html))

Comment: Ah, any way to set the lambda up so it just gets triggered periodically (once/day) without it being started by invoking that path?

Comment: @KristofPlennings sure using your Schedule event is correct to do such things. with `sam local` you need to use `generate-event` then.. see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and it returns a sample payload in the trend of: { "source": "aws.events" ... But my actual handleRequest doesn't seem to be executed. (handleRequest should create a dir to test it's doing something, but it's not being created). Thank you so much already. And noticed I should have checked: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/test-sam-cli.html better

Comment: you need to invoke it `sam local invoke function-name -e event_file.json`

Answer (score 14):

**For Googlers:**

- Check whether you have an `Event` with `Type: Api`
- ALSO check whether you have run `sam build` (*very important*)
- Use the `--debug` flag so you will know what is going on

As of 2020/7/13, `Type: HttpApi` does not work with `sam local start-api`. See [issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1641).

Answer (score 3):

This error message also displays if you are trying to test a websocket API locally. Unfortunately, local testing of websockets is not currently supported - see https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/896.

Comment: any update here, is it supported now :-)? any workaround found?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error too even when I *did* have an `Api` event defined in my SAM template. The problem was that I had a previous template in my `.aws-sam/build/` directory which didn't have the Api event defined (from a previous run of `sam build`). Cleaning out the build directory fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting this error, but I have function that is working with the `HttpApi`, it appears that current version of `sam` does not support `HttpApi`.

**CLI Version**

`SAM CLI, version 0.52.0`

**Example Function**

```
FeedsFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri:
    Description: "Function that handles feeds"
    Events:
      Handler:
        Type: HttpApi
        Properties:
          ApiId: !Ref FeedsApi
          Path: /
          Method: get
    Handler: api
    MemorySize: 1024
    Runtime: go1.x
    Timeout: 5
    Tracing: Active
```

> There is currently an open issue on GitHub for adding support: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1641

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had a whitespace error in my AWS::Serverless::Function definition, specifically `Environment` needed to be a child of `Properties` but was on the same level. Correcting the whitespace made this error disappear. Nodejs 10.15.